# solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x}$ using L'Hospitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having problems with this question. I know the answer is 0 but I keep getting infinity over infinity. I am using L'Hospitals rule.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

edit* I only used L'Hospitals rule once.
edit*** Now it works when I use it 3 times :)

Comment: Can you show your calculations?

Comment: Use the L'Hospital rule $3$ times and you get the limit $0$.

Comment: I use L'Hospitals rule once? Can you use it 3 times?

Comment: You can use it as many as you have the indeterminate form.

Answer (score 8):

There will be situtation in which you may need to use L'Hospital's rule more than once, and in this case, you need to apply it three times:$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {x^3}{e^x} \quad \overset{L'H}{=}\quad \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3x^2}{e^x}\quad \overset{L'H} = \quad \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{6x}{e^x}\quad \overset{L'H} =\quad \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{6}{e^x} = 0$$

You may apply L'Hospital repeatedly, provided (and only so long as) your limit evaluates to an *indeterminate form.*

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach is to use the fact that for any $x>0$ the quantity $e^x$ is the limit of the increasing sequence given by $a_n = \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$, so, for example, $e^x > a_4$ and:
$$0<\frac{x^3}{e^x}<\frac{x^3}{(1+x/4)^4}=\frac{1}{1+x/4}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{1+x/4}\right)^3<\frac{4^3}{1+x/4},$$
where the limit of the RHS for $x\to +\infty$ is clearly zero.

Comment: In general $e^x$ grows faster than $x^n$ for any fixed $n$ as $x \to \infty$.