# How can we determine the number of terms which we have to take in a series to get a particular accurate?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

As I remember , two days ago , there was a question ( [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475035/solve-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-fracx3ex-using-lhospitals-rule/475037#475037) ) asks for calculating this limit

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{x^3}{e^x}$ and the question was answered .

of course this is an easy limit , we can calculate it using l'hopital rule .

Now ,  if I expressed $\displaystyle e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots  = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}$ and substitute back an approximation for $e^x$.

If we approximated $e^x$ for 3 terms then the limit is $\infty$ , if we approximated it for 4 terms then the limit is 6 but if we approximated for 5 terms then we get the right answer which is 0 .

Now , How can we know that approximation for 5 terms will work while approximation for 4 or 3 terms would fail ? Is there any test or analytical method to determine this ?

I used the geometric approach to see the reason behind that . here is the sketch for those approximations and the original function which illustrate and show why approximation for  3 and 4 terms fail . but I ask for Analytical approach as using the sketch of approximations is not rigorous and practical in general .

[image]

Comment: @robjohn , I substituted the approximation and then calculate the limit using the fact that , $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} 1/x = 0$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what the question was asking. It seems the question is why
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}}&=\infty\tag{1}\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}}&=6\tag{2}\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}}&=0\tag{3}\\
\end{align}
$$
while
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x}=0\tag{4}
$$
In actuality, $e^x$ grows faster than any power of $x$. We see why in the example of $x^3$ above. First of all, for $x\ge0$
$$
e^x\ge1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{5}
$$
for *any* $n$.

---

Thus, $(5)$ (substituting $n\mapsto n+1$) implies
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}
\le&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1{x^n}+\frac1{x^{n-1}}+\frac1{2x^{n-2}}+\frac1{6x^{n-3}}+\dots+\frac1{n!}+\frac{x}{(n+1)!}}\\
\le&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{x}\\[14pt]
=&0\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

---

If we'd used one fewer term in the denominator of $(6)$, we would get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}
\le&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{x^n}{n!}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1{x^n}+\frac1{x^{n-1}}+\frac1{2x^{n-2}}+\frac1{6x^{n-3}}+\dots+\frac1{x(n-1)!}+\frac1{n!}}\\[4pt]
=&n!\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
because we are using a polynomial of the same order as the numerator to approximate $e^x$ near $x=\infty$.

---

If we'd used two fewer terms in the denominator of $(6)$, we would get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}
\le&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots+\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1{x^n}+\frac1{x^{n-1}}+\frac1{2x^{n-2}}+\frac1{6x^{n-3}}+\dots+\frac1{x^2(n-2)!}+\frac1{x(n-1)!}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1{x^{n-1}}+\frac1{x^{n-2}}+\frac1{2x^{n-3}}+\frac1{6x^{n-4}}+\dots+\frac1{x(n-2)!}+\frac1{(n-1)!}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot(n-1)!\\[9pt]
=&\infty\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
because we are using a polynomial of a lower order than the numerator to approximate $e^x$ near $x=\infty$.

---

However, given $(6)$, $(7)$, and $(8)$, we can easily conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}\le\min(0,n!,\infty)=0\tag{9}
$$

Comment: your answer is great! but suppose I want to calculate the number of terms in the series of the function $g(x)$ which gives me the exact limit , How can I calculate this ? How can we calculate the accuracy of some approximation of a function ?

Comment: @FawzyHegab: there are so many kinds of problems, it is hard to give a formula or even a method that will work. You've seen what was done in this particular kind of problem. However, in general, power series are not what you want to use for looking at limits at infinity.

Comment: What kind of series could work when looking at limits at infinity ?

Comment: You should look at [asymptotic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) for estimates at infinity.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the sum doesn't really approximate $e^x$ "in a neighborhood of $\infty$". The nicer argument is that for any $n$ that we pick $$e^x=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\geqslant \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Thus for any monomial $x^m$ we can simply pick $n>m$ and write $$\frac{x^m}{e^x}\leqslant n!{x^{m-n}}\to 0$$

as $x\to\infty$. The argument of omitting terms is just ill founded if you're looking for a "tight" approximatio $-$ else, you're gust getting crude overestimates. You can "omit" some terms when $x\to 0$, but here we're looking at $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Well, you've omitted some terms, just more than the original argument.

Comment: @robjohn Sure, but the essence of the argument is another.

Comment: As I state in my answer, for $x\ge0$, $e^x\ge1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for any $n$. Therefore, you can omit terms from the expansion near $\infty$, as long as you are looking for an underestimate and not looking for the big-O type estimate for the error.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff , Ok , your method is also Great! but there is no problem to omit some terms here even x approaches infinity ! as I omitted $\frac{1}{x}$ not { x } .